# Extracting an (almost) independent large subset from a pairwise independent set of Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n>1$, and let $X_1,X_2, \ldots ,X_n$ be non-constant random variables with values in $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. Let us say that a subset of variables $X_{i_1},X_{i_2}, \ldots,X_{i_d}$ is **complete** if the vector $\overrightarrow{X}=(X_{i_1},\ldots,X_{i_d})$ satisfies $P(\overrightarrow{X}=\overrightarrow{c})>0$ for any $\overrightarrow{c}\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^d$.

Prove or find a counterexample :  if $X_1,X_2, \ldots ,X_n$ are pairwise independent Bernoulli variables, then we may extract a complete subset of cardinality at least $t+1$, where $t$ is the largest integer satisfying $2^{t} \leq n$.

This is true for $n=3$ (and hence also true for $n$ between $3$ and $7$), as is shown  in the main answer to that [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66738/is-there-a-good-explanation-for-this-fact-on-pairwise-independent-variables). (That other [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64973/sufficiently-random-sample) is also related, and provides several links)

If true, this result is sharp, as can be seen by the classical example of taking all arbitrary sums modulo 2 of an initial set of fully independent $t+1$ Bernoulli variables. This produces a set of pairwise independent $2^{t+1}-1$ variables, and where the maximal cardinality of a complete subset is $t+1$.

**Update 10/10/2012** : By induction, it would suffice to show the following : if $X_1, \ldots ,X_t$ is a fully independent set of $t$ Bernoulli variables and $X$ is another Bernoulli variable, such that the pair $(X_i,X)$ is independent for each $i$, then there are coefficients $\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_1, \ldots ,\varepsilon_t$ in $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ such that, if we put

$$
H=\Bigg\lbrace (x_1,\ldots,x_t,x) \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace ^{t+1} \Bigg| x=\varepsilon_0+\sum_{k=1}^{t}\varepsilon_kx_k \ {\sf mod} \ 2\Bigg\rbrace,  \ \overrightarrow{X}=(X_{1},\ldots,X_{t},X)
$$
then $P(\overrightarrow{X}=h)>0$ for any $h\in H$.